# Javascript: return html element from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter certain html element using the `datetime` attributes. My html elements looks like

```
<time title="Sat Dec 22 16:29:21 2012 UTC" datetime="2012-12-22T16:29:21+00:00">4 hours</time>
```

Now, what I am doing is

```
var x = $("p time").map(function() { filter(this);})
```

and my filter function looks like:

```
function filter(var1){

  var now = new Date();
  var time = $(var1).attr("datetime");

  var time = new Date(time);
  var diff = now - time;

  if( diff < 7200000){

   console.log("yes");
   return $(var1).parent().parent();

  }
}
```

When I run the above code I get `x` as an `empty array` and `yes` is printed 9 times.

So, my question is why my `filter` function is not returning the parent html tag.

Comment: you are missing `return` from the function you pass to `map()`

Comment: If you're trying to compare dates, you're also missing getTime() to get the timestamp. And you're redeclearing the time variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x = $("p time").map(function() { filter(this); });
```

Should be

```
var x = $("p time").map(function() { return filter(this); });
```

You're missing the return statement.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I should sleep now.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `filter()` method

```
var p_parents_I_want = $("p time").filter(function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var time = $(this).attr("datetime");
    time = new Date(time);/* don't declare same var twice*/
    var diff = now - time;

    return diff < 7200000

}).parent().parent()
```

Can usually replace `parent().parent()` using `closest(selector)`

API reference:  http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Cool, didn't knew about this.

Comment: `map()` likely uses `filter()` internally in jQuery, but what you want is the elements so this method makes most sense to me